# TypeScript cannot derive type constraint inside function type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, type-constraints, conditional-types

Suppose I have a constrained type function `type Foo<T extends string>` that only accepts types that extend `string`. I would expect the following code to compile. Instead, it gives a type error.

```
type Foo<T extends string> = T;

type UseFoo1<T> = NonNullable<T> extends string
  ? (param: Foo<NonNullable<T>>) => void
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
  : () => void;
```

```
Type 'NonNullable<T>' does not satisfy the constraint 'string'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Why can't TypeScript derive that `NonNullable<T>` extends `string`?

---

In the following cases, it *does* work.

```
type UseFoo2<T> = T extends string
  ? (param: Foo<T>) => void
  : () => void;

type UseFoo3<T> = NonNullable<T> extends string
  ? Foo<NonNullable<T>>
  : never;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *general*, there is a trade-off between the usefulness you get by tracking every type fact logically implied by a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) check and the usefulness you get by skipping them.  Tracking them gives you more information, and skipping them gives you better compiler performance.  And tracking can be hard to do correctly, also.  When you have `WWW extends XXX ? YYY : ZZZ`, it's not always correct to propagate the new `XXX` constraint on the `WWW` expression all the way down into the `YYY` type expression, in the face of [variance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218); if `WWW` appears in a *covariant* position in `YYY` then it is fine to propagate the constraint, but if it appears in a *contravariant* position then it is not always desirable to do this.  So I'd say that no matter how the TS team decides to implement such constraint propagation, there will be unmet use cases.

In *particular*, it looks like you're seeing a side effect of a bug fix for [microsoft/TypeScript#43427](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43427), where the following code was giving an error:

```
type Q<T> = number extends T ? (n: number) => void : never;
function fn<T>(arg: Q<T>) {
  arg(10); // error in TS 4.2-, okay in TS 4.3+
}
```

The compiler was narrowing `number` to the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `number & T`, and then complaining that `10` is not obviously assignable to `number & T`.  Because `number` appears in a contravariant position in `(n: number) => void`, this *narrowing* of `number` made the function type *wider* and less useful.

A fix was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#43439](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43439) not to propagate constraints to contravariant positions, with another fix in [microsoft/TypeScript#43599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43599) to specifically re-enable this propagation if the checked type is a type parameter (like `T` and unlike `number` or `NonNullable<T>`).  This fixes the above error in TypeScript 4.3 and above, but introduces the error you ran into.

---

So that's why it's happening.  Since type parameters are exempted from this you can possibly work around it by using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to copy your type into a new type parameter, and in TS4.7 and up you can even [re-constrain the checked type](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/#extends-constraints-on-infer-type-variables) so that the refactoring doesn't actually change your code that much:

```
type UseFoo2<T> = NonNullable<T> extends infer NNT extends string ?
  (param: Foo<NNT>) => void : () => void; // okay
```

This copies `NonNullable<T>` into the `NNT` type parameter but we only go into the true branch if `NNT` is constrained to `string`. And you can use `NNT` in any position that needs a type constrained to `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFShAHsCA7AJgZyn2ACcBLbAcwD4oBeKZAbgCgXRIoBVfCeOAIwpaDAHJxsogK4AbGQEMARjIjC0mHASKkKlFlCgB+KAAow8kvIC2ALlgJE4ybIXLVyatQCU9WgDc4MlwoAHoQqDgAa3kQRgBlABYAOgAmAFoAGjQSEjgSeOSAZgBqfSg7Ex86f0DcVnZwaB4+BBS1MQlpOSUVNQwsPEIKADMIfNFRVH7NQmJyKiMyswtrO35HSe9fKACg8tMqmqD6hs4ARXaobCkrRTH1Aa1UYxNsO2vbscOd2v3sCD8Y1Ywyk2AAxsAyBIoMNsMITBZKHYLh4fABvMqIkwCAAMXiYoXCY1y+WQiVSmWyJIKSRKLAAviwgA)